# Get State of Maven Execution within Shell Script

Tags: shell, maven

I'd like to know whether there's a way to kind of 'query' the state of an Maven execution from within a Shell script (used for build process).

The point is that I would like to let the whole build script fail as soon as a single error appears within one of the Shell scripts Maven executions.

e.g.

```
(0) mvn -f .../someDir clean
(1) mvn -f .../1/pom.xml install
(2) mvn -f .../2/pom.xml -PgenerateWadl
```

So if e.g. there occurs an error within (0), then (1) and (2) must no more be executed, but instead the build script should quit with an error message directly after (0).

I'm not THAT much into Shell scripting, but I know of the $? variable to get the return value of an earlier execution. But as Maven simply seems to write errors out to the console, this might not work, does it?

I would have liked to research more information concerning the "$?", but it's quite hard to google for it.

Comment: $? DOES contain the state of the Maven execution, as well.

Answer (score 6):

A simple way is to use the `-e` option.

```
set -e
mvn -f .../somedir clean
mvn -f .../otherdir install
mvn -f .../thirddir -PgenerateWadl package
```

This will automatically have the shell exit with error if any command in sequence exits with a non-zero status (unless it is part of an explicit test such as an `if` or `while` or a chain like `a || b`).

You can watch this happen by inserting a call to `false` between any of the Maven calls.

See the [`set` POSIX spec](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/set.html) for details on `set -e`.

Comment: for your reply - actually this makes life easier concerning testing on $? after each execution. But now - how can I get the original exception that was produced by the Maven execution. Is there a way to split advise Maven to write to stderr, too?

Comment: I'm not aware of any Maven native way to get Maven to output errors to stderr.  You could `tee` the output to a file and `grep` for "[WARNING]"s but that's obviously sub-optimal.  Perhaps take a look at Hudson (or other CI system), which probably has some support for parsing Maven's output.

Comment: nice solution!.

Answer (score 2):

```
mvn ... && mvn ... && mvn ...
```

The execution will only proceed if the previous one was successful.